# Multiple Routers, Cannot access their settings after they are setup?

Tags: networking, router

I have been having a horrible time trying to maintain this network I setup over the years.

First I will go through what I have, and how it is setup.

192.168.88.1 - My ISP, rural wifi, has my on some router that is probably a virtual router running on their tower (I doubt they have a individual router for every person, and I doubt it is packaged in the dish they installed). I can set static ips for the DHCP server in this and do some port forwarding. THis router provides 1 LAN connection spot.

192.168.88.7 - I then have FreshTomato router LANed to this. It has wireless turned of and connects to my PC and the router downstairs.

192.168.88.4- This Smart/RG supplies the house wifi and LAN for the TV.

The huge ongoing issue is that whenever I set stuff up, the routers always become invisible. They have static IPs,I know their IPs, I am on the right subnet. But I cannot access them. So anytime I want to change anything, I have to do a factory reset and try to remember all the important settings.

Right now, strangely, my PC cannot access any of the routers, and it HAS internet access. But my Wireless tablet does not have internet access, but CAN access both routers. Both devices have the right ips, wireless devices were working after I made my last changes, and I could still access the router's from my PC, but then something changed overnight and both these things broke. I do not understand how they are broken in this way, but I am sure I can mess with the DHCP server setting to get internet back, but my main issue is that is si really hard to work on anything when the routers close down and do not let my access them as soon as they are connected to the network.

Update: Went through and turned off all the DHCP servers I had access to, and switched the DNS server to 88.1. I now have access to the routers on my PC, and have Internet on both, but lost access to the 88.7 on my wireless device. Also, this is a common occurrence, after everything restarts I will probably be back to not having access again.

Comment: It is actually very likely that the dish is a router. Mikrotik wireless bridges run exactly the same OS as their other products, with standard routing features available (including DHCP, web interface, etc). Other manufacturers do this as well, e.g. I manage a few old airMax connections where the antenna on the roof does routing.

Comment: What subnets are configured on your two routers? Do they have DHCP enabled? How did you _verify_ that you're on the right subnet? (Having an address from the same subnet number isn't always a reliable indication, as you might end up with multiple physically separate subnets that just happen to be numbered identically.)

Comment: Ah, I guess that might by an issue. I have never really played around with the subnet, or really learned anything about it. It looks like both my routers are set to the standard x.x.x.0 . but no idea what the isps subnet is, and I do not think there is anyway to find out directly.

Comment: Unfortunately "x.x.x.0" tells me completely nothing. (I was not asking about the _subnet mask_, but about the actual subnet address.) Does the SmartRG have 192.168.88.4 as its LAN address or as its WAN address? If that's the WAN address, what is its LAN configuration like?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. from my understanding WAN address is the address used to connect to the internet. Any internet facing network has 1 of these and appears as a random jumble of numbers in the form of "205.34.154.87". But every device has a LAN address, almost exclusively of the form 192.168.X.Y. Where X is static and normally 1, but in my case 88, and Y is the number of the specific device. all the ip addresses listed in my post are LAN addresses.

Comment: Before answering that, _which ports_ on each router are connected to what? As far as I know, FreshTomato has a distinct 'WAN' port and 'LAN' ports like most other home routers. Which port did you use to connect it to the .88.1 router? (And same for the SmartRG?)

Comment: They are all connected to lan ports